# Why is the number of carbonyl stretches in the IR spectrum different for solid state samples compared to samples in solution?

Tags: spectroscopy

I am comparing two IR spectrums of the same molecule, one in the solid state and one in $\ce{CH2Cl2}$ solution. There is only one CO group in the molecule.

Why does the solid state spectrum show two carbonyl stretches, while the solution spectrum has only one carbonyl stretch?

Comment: Please provide more information about your molecule and the spectra, and the preparation of samples. In its current state the question is very vague and broad.

Comment: In solution, the material to be characterised experiences a different environment than in its own matrix.  *In extremis* there is nujol as apolar matrix, and KCl as salty matrix, for example. In the pure solid state, the accessibility of vibrational states may be a different one, in particular in the crystalline state where special sites and their local symmetry may allow / disallow vibrations to occur (in case of perovskites, for example).